# endless loop when rewriting from root to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all requests to dev directory from root except root files.

**example.com/anything** to **example.com/dev/index.php?url=anything** .

my htaccess in public_html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) /dev/?url=$1 [QSA,NC,R]
```

It is causing an endless loop error when I visit http://example.com/anything what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have `R` (redirect) flag here? Won't it expose your internal URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev

RewriteRule (.*) /dev/$1 [QSA,NC,R]
```

Cause of the endless loop is probably that your destination url "/dev/?url=$1" is redirecting back to itself. Because there is no condition in your rule to prevent it from redirecting to itself if "/dev" is not a real directory.

```
example.com/anything
```

is redirecting to

```
example.com/dev/?url=anything
```

And on the second iteration

```
  example.com/dev/?url=anything
```

is redirecting to

```
example.com/dev/?url=dev
```

.......

it continues to loop untill the last iteration.

You can solve this by adding the following condition to your rule

@Hereblur is right, you should add :

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev
```

as it ignores the uri if it is starting with "/dev" and skips the rule.

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to exclude your `dev` from redirecting.

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
```